# Cascading dropDownLists in repeater. DropDownLists with SQL source and add/delete option

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater, sqldatasource

What is the trick to implement the following interface in ASP.NET?

[image: repeater]

I think the screenshot should explain everything.

1. Both dropDownLists work on SQL tables. [Categories],[Items] bound with ID_category PK/FK
2. Number of rows variable (by default 1 row with "Add" button)
3. Choosing category changes only the content of the dropDownList next to it and the content stays the same when other rows get added/deleted
4. "Add" button saves current setup and adds new row with either "Select value" or eventually 1st category/1st item selected

**How to store previously selected categories/items and the dropDown filtering by category, while adding, changing, deleting items or some other PostBack on website?**

---

What I have tried so far is to use Repeater with DataSet, however I have encountered several different problems:

- Was unable to preserve the relations between previous dropDowns
- DropDowns resetting one another
- 2nd dropDown losing filtering when adding new row

I can post some code but since it doesn't fully work, perhaps a totally different approach would be better. Basically I started with [this](http://ranafaisal.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/dynamically-adding-removing-textboxes-in-aspnet-repeater/) tutorial. The repeater currently looks like:

```
<repeater>
<itemtemplate>
  <dropDown DataSource="categoriesDS" 
     value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category") %>'.../>
  <dropDown DataSource="itemsDS" 
     value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item") %>'.../>
  <button CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Button") %>' 
     Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Button") %>' .../>
</itemtemplate>
</repeater>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or solutions and I hope it'll be helpful for others.

Comment: Do they all have to be hierarchical?

Comment: In pairs. Category > Item, Category > Item.

Comment: I assume you are saving or holding the current dropdown values somewhere?  Have you tried using the repeaters OnItemDataBound method to set the SelectedValue of the dropdown?

Comment: As I recall, it caused errors. It's an old question, I went different way, but I would still like to know how to achieve this. Perhaps not only me.

Answer (score 1):

[Ajax Cascading DropDownlist](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

It is very simple to use.

Comment: Having for example 4 of these dropDown pairs, will it preserve the selected values of 3rd and 4th group if I delete 2nd? By pair I mean both category and item. Writing cascading dropDown lists is easy, but handling dynamic adding and deleting these was the problem.